# CompilerError: WebAssembly.instatiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d ,but found 28 6d 6f 64 @+0

Tags: node.js, webassembly

```
(module
(func (export "addTwo") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
 local.get 0
 local.get 1
 i32.add))

 //this is my addTwo.wasm file

 const fs = require('fs');
 const buf = fs.readFileSync('./addTwo.wasm');// importing addTwo.wasm file
 const lib = WebAssembly.instantiate(new Uint8Array(buf)).
   then(res => res.instance.exports).catch(err=> console.log(err))
 console.log(lib)
 console.log(lib.addTwo(2,2))

 //this is my addTwo.js file
```

I am just trying to add two numbers, but got the error:

> [CompilerError: WebAssembly.instatiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d ,but found 28 6d 6f 64 @+0]

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the WebAssembly module to binary form before it can be loaded by an engine.  You can do this you wat2wasm (from wabt) or wasm-as (from binaryen).

Comment: Thanks a lot !, can you please suggest me  any tutioral for web assembly